# Spoofing file descriptor in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing an library which will transmit data via multiple routes; TCP, UDP, RDMA (Remote Direct Memory Access) and occasionally via a straight function call where client/server are rolled into a single binary.

I'll be handling TCP, UDP, RDMA with file descriptors and have been looking at how I could achieve somethign similar with a FunctionCallSocket class which would take the rough form:

```
class FunctionCallSocket
{
    public:
        FunctionCallSocket();
        ~FunctionCallSocket();

        void send(char* buf, std::size_t len);
        void recv(char* dest, std::size_t len);

    private:
        char*  m_outboundBuffer;
        char*  m_inboundBuffer;
};
```

I'd like to do is be able to treat the class like a file descriptor whereby I could pass it along with TCP, UDP, etc. file handles to a select/epoll.

From what I understand the file descriptor integer value is generated by the OS from a privately held table which maps files to id's so I'd somehow need to spoof this.

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use OS-specific calls to get file descriptors, if you want to.  For example, the Unix open function would do just what you want.

Alternatively, you could make your code to read and write data part of a polymorphic class hierarchy, which would let you use file descriptors where appropriate and the streams library (for example) for file I/O.  In fact, one idea might be to writw custom stream classes to wrap up the TCP connections, then use ostream and istream as wrappers around the specifics of the connection.

Comment: Interesting. Calling open would certainly reserve me a unique file descriptor. I wouldn't actually be sending data via the file descriptor, but via a function call on an pointer the FunctionCallObject owns. Would there be a way change the fd when data arrives on the inboundBuffer/outboundBuffer so select/epoll see's the data?

Comment: **Comment from seperate answer:** Clients using this library will be using their own thread(s) to disptach from the file handles. They will also be disptahcing from seperate file handles outwith this library. I want to unify the dispatch process by using select/epoll.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on Linux, I suggest looking into eventfd - this does exactly what you're looking for.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/eventfd.2.html

Open the fd in EFD_SEMAPHORE mode and you can use it to keep track of how many queued events you have

(each write() call will increment the counter stored by the kernel with the eventfd, and each read() will decrement the counter)

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a file descriptor, then there is no point in passing it to select(). If there is a file descriptor somewhere underneath, then you either need an API to expose it, or you have a low-level API to add file descriptors to the select set and make the class responsible for registering any file descriptors it uses. Note that you are well into asynchronous event handling and callback territory then.

Comment: Clients using this library will be using their own thread(s) to disptach from the file handles. They will also be disptahcing from seperate file handles outwith this library. I want to unify the dispatch process by using select/epoll.

Comment: That isn't as easy as it sounds. If there is a file descriptor somewhere below that, and the semantics are the same, then it is possible to do without major changes, however in my experience, that is seldom the case. The Linux USB subsystem uses file descriptors, for example, but completion of an URB is signalled by the FD becoming "writeable", so you end up with lots of special cases.

Comment: I wouldn't actually be sending data via the file descriptor, but via a function call on an pointer the FunctionCallObject owns. I simply need to reserve an fd so it doesn't get assigned to something else and then somehow change a flag on the fd when data arrives on the char* buffers within FunctionCallSocket.

Comment: While I totally recommend against it, you could open an anonymous pipe or socket, which gives you two file descriptors; writing into one makes the other readable until you read the data out from it.

Comment: @Simon: It's possible to do this with a single socket, eg. local bound UDP socket connected to itself.

Comment: I think that should be possible, although some operating systems may show funny behaviour. If the app is ported to Windows, opening an UDP socket will trigger a firewall warning, for example. I think I should again stress that I do not think this is a good idea, and it certainly would raise a red flag if I ever saw an application talking to itself like that.